# Saving canvas image in phonegap after canvas is drawn

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am creating a image in a canvas and saving the image. I found a very nice plugin [here](https://github.com/jsphkhan/rialabphonegap).

Code for the image saving:

```
          var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
          var imageObj = new Image();
          imageObj.src = imageURI;
          imageObj.onload = function() {
            contentW = $("#content").width();
            canvas.width = 400;
            canvas.height = 600;
            context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

            //the plugin
            setTimeout(function(){
            window.savephotoplugin(canvas,"image/png",device.version,function(val){ 
                    //returns you the saved path in val 
                    alert("Photo Saved: " + val);   
                });
            },3000) 
        }
```

The plugin works very nice only problem is that it is done before the canvas is even drawn. So I put a setTimeout to avoid it, however is there a way to detect when canvas is done and call the function after it. Tried jquery .change() didn't work.

If anyone finds this code useful feel free to use and the plugin is very nice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [drawImage](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/#drawing-images-to-the-canvas) doesn't accept any callbacks. Also canvas doesn't define any events about its drawing process. So you choice of `timeout` is correct. Only one thing you could possibly improve. Use `setTimeout(..., 0)` instead of `setTimeout(..., 3000)`. More details about this trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful)